# Auto-adjust columns height on prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I'm trying to fit full-width information under these columns.
With this code

```
column_box([13.75, cursor], columns: 2, width: bounds.width, reflow_margins: true) do
  items.each do |item|
    if item_total.items.present?
      item_table(item)
      move_down 7
    end
  end
end
.
.
.
table(another_table_data, width: bounds.width, column_widths: { column_widths },
      header: true, position: 27.5, :cell_style => { inline_format: true, size: 13,
                                                     align: :center, border_width: 0.1,
                                                     border_color: '006c8b',
                                                     valign: :center })
```

I get this:

[image]

How can I automatically resize column heights to get this?:

[image]

EDIT: Even if the content of the column ends before the end of the page, it uses the entire height of the page, like this:

[image]